# Why doesn't OpenGL correctly display the image I loaded?

Tags: image, delphi, opengl

I have two images, both are 24 color .bmp 32x32 pixels.  If I load one with OpenGL it works, if I load the other with OpenGL it just shows black and white lines.

Is there something else that could be different, thus not letting one of the images show?

This one does not work in code:

[image: grass1.bmp]

This one does work in code:

[image: grass.bmp]

Also checked info size and file header size. Both images were 40 on info and 14 on file size. Both images biWidth and BiHeight were still 32x32.

This shows how I texture a hex with the image grass

```
//GRASS
glTexImage2d(GL_TEXTURE_2D,Level,Colorcomps,sGrass,tGrass,Border,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,grass);
glLoadName(1);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for I := 0 to 6 do
    begin
      glTexCoord2f(COS(i/6.0*2*PI),SIN(i/6.0*2*pi));
      glVertex3f((((COS(i/6.0*2*PI)/12)+offsetx)+0.2),((SIN(i/6.0*2*pi)/12)+offsety),-2);
    end;
glEnd;
```

`grass` is a pointer and filled like so:

```
grass := Readbitmap('Grass.bmp',sGrass,tGrass);
```

And how do I get the image data (which should be OK as it works with other images, I really think its something else about an image that would make the two different)?

```
Function TFCreateMap.ReadBitmap(const FilePath:String;var sWidth,tHeight:GLsizei):pointer;
const
  szh=SizeOf(TBitmapFileHeader);
  szi=SizeOf(TBitmapInfoHeader);
var
  bmpfile: file;
  bfh:TBitmapFileHeader;
  bmi:TBitmapInfoHeader;
  t:byte;
  x,
  fpos,
  size: integer;
begin
  assignfile(bmpfile,FilePath);
  reset(bmpfile,1);
  size := FileSize(bmpfile)-szh-szi;
  blockread(bmpfile,bfh,szh);
  if bfh.bfType<>$4D42  then
    raise EinvalidGraphic.Create('Invalid Bitmap');
  blockread(bmpfile,bmi,szi);
  with bmi do
  begin
    sWidth := biWidth;
    tHeight := biHeight;
  end;
  getmem(result,size);
  blockread(bmpfile,result^,size);
  for x  := 0 to sWidth*tHeight-1 do
  with TWrap(result^)[x] do
  begin
    t := r;
    r := b;
    b := t;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It's hard to compare those images if we don't have them, but try for instance check the value of the `biHeight` of the `TBitmapInfoHeader` structure. This can be negative value and maybe the function you're passing that value to doesn't take negative values. But it's just a guess since I don't know those images and you didn't show what are you doing with that `ReadBitmap` method.

Comment: I will test and see if there is a difference in the values, give me a few mins. But with ReadBitmap, i am pretty much just removing the infoheader and file header, before sending the data to opengl. Storing the data into a pointer called "grass". Where it is used uptop. I can try to give links to the images, but not sure if i uploaded them to a photo site if it would change them in any way. but will do both in a few mins.

Comment: updated post with images. and header info / height info

Comment: The difference between those two bitmaps is in the bits per pixel value. The [bitmap](http://turboimg.com/p/aur1361433642q.bmp) which fails you to display is 8-bit whilst the working one is 24-bit. In case of 8-bit bitmap, each byte in the pixel array represents one pixel, so your color transformation in the end of your method actually move the pixels. Also try to [find the answer](http://www.graphicsgroups.com/6-opengl/8237a6fa51e21b45.htm) if the `glTexImage2d` function even supports 8-bit bitmaps.

Comment: very weird, as i was using windows 7 when i open the image and saved it as a 24 bit image (windows paint).  Here at work i open the image and saved it as 24 bit ..again.. (windows xp) and now it works.. I wonder if windows 7 paint is doing something different.. Strange but at least i understand why its black and white now. Also how did you find out it was 8 bit and not 24?  if you could just put that along with what you said as answer ill gladly accept

Comment: The number of bits per pixel is stored in the `biBitCount` member of the [`TBitmapInfoHeader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx) structure.

Comment: Do you find that your TWrap code at the end works the way you want? You're essentially assigning `b := r` because you overwrite the original value of `t` in the first statement. To rotate the values of three variables, you'll need a forth temporary variable.

Comment: @RobKennedy yes it shows up correctly. T is the temporary variable, Red and Blue is being switched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bitmaps differ at least in bit depth. The one which fails you to load is 8-bit, whilst the working one is 24-bit. What you need is to convert your 8-bit bitmap to 24-bit (because of the used `format` parameter value in your [`glTexImage2D`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) function call).

***Code review:***

I've made a review of your code and here's the result; the following code uses file stream for reading the file (since I'm not a fan of the old style I/O routines; anyway you forgot on file closing), removes the color channel rotation part which was, as @Rob pointed wrong (for the reason mentioned below). I've added a check for the necessary bit depth value (which must be 24-bit with the `format` flag you will use for the [`glTexImage2D`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) function call):

```
function TFCreateMap.ReadBitmap(const AFilePath: string; var AWidth, 
  AHeight: GLsizei): Pointer;
var
  DataSize: Integer;
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  FileHeader: TBitmapFileHeader;
  InfoHeader: TBitmapInfoHeader;
const
  FileTypeBitmap = $4D42;
  FileHeaderSize = SizeOf(TBitmapFileHeader);
  InfoHeaderSize = SizeOf(TBitmapInfoHeader);
begin 
  Result := nil;                              

  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(AFilePath, fmOpenRead);
  try
    FileStream.ReadBuffer(FileHeader, FileHeaderSize);
    if (FileHeader.bfType <> FileTypeBitmap) then
      raise EinvalidGraphic.Create('Invalid file type!');

    FileStream.ReadBuffer(InfoHeader, InfoHeaderSize);
    if (InfoHeader.biBitCount <> 24) then
      raise EinvalidGraphic.Create('Invalid bit depth!');

    DataSize := FileStream.Size - FileHeaderSize - InfoHeaderSize;
    GetMem(Result, DataSize);
    FileStream.ReadBuffer(Result^, DataSize);

    AWidth := InfoHeader.biWidth;
    AHeight := InfoHeader.biHeight;    
  finally
    FileStream.Free;
  end;    
end;
```

Now to the reason, why I removed the color channel rotation; I have almost no experience with OpenGL, but something tells me, that `GL_BGR` value of the `format` parameter of the [`glTexImage2D`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) function might simplify this part, because I'd say that the function then expects the BGR pixel array for its `data` parameter and that's how your bitmaps are stored. So my guess is that you can leave the color channel rotation and call the [`glTexImage2D`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) function with `GL_BGR` value of the `format` parameter:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Level, Colorcomps, sGrass, tGrass, Border, GL_BGR,
  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, grass);
...
```

Comment: After looking at the [alternative way](http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/s/4ad5ff79dd9daa2d80afdfe69ef94a99/topic-263976.html) and running a simple test I can confirm my expectation. You can remove the color channel rotation and simply use `GL_BGR` value for the `format` parameter.

Comment: yes is was to adjust the color read in as i was told opengl reads in RGB, where windows saves it as BGR .. I did not see the options for GL_BGR in opengGL but glad its there :D.  Thansk alot

Answer (score 2):

First image has index color format, but second image have RGB. You can try to change color format using GIMP or other editor.